# How to disable the warning about using deprecated gets in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, exploit, gcc-warning, gets

I'm running a CTF and I am currently writing a problem that exploits C's `gets` function. I understand that the function is deprecated and dangerous and **I would never use it in any other circumstance**. Unfortunately, `gcc` compiles my code and when I run the binary when the `gets` function is hit, I get a friendly error message:

```
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
```

This would normally be great, because it warns you that gets is unsafe, but unfortunately, in my CTF, I think that this error message makes the problem a bit too easy. Do you know how I would go about disabling this warning? Thanks!

```sh
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: It looks like you're actually using clang, not gcc.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what's a CTF?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I think it's a type of organized "wargames" hacking competition: https://ctftime.org/ctf-wtf/

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from not using `gets`? You can write your own unsafe `mygets` based on `fgets` (about 3-4 lines of code), or based on `fgetc` (~5-6 lines of code).

Comment: I just realized that your warning has nothing to do with GCC itself - So the question title seems to be misplaced. The warning you got is from macOS about executing a program which uses `gets()`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky post this as answer since this is best solution for competition like CFT. Current answer with `#pragma` doesn't improve how easy problem can be spotted.

Comment: @MarekR the answer below covers this already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: I just realized that your question title seems to be misplaced - The warning you got is from macOS about executing a program which uses `gets()`. It has nothing to do with the compilation by using GCC.

:-/ Any way, I let my answer alive for reference.

Just as comment: I googled a bit about what you are looking for, but there seems to be no reliable way to disable this warning when executing the program. One suggested rebuilding `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` without any result or experience if it indeed works, but I personally think this a bit too extreme and even can be harmful. - I do not recommend this technique.

If you really want to create an exploit program, try to rebuild `gets()` by a costum-made function and name the function a bit different, like f.e. `gets_c()`. This should be a workaround to disable this warning from macOS.

---

Old answer (regarding GCC itself):

First of all, you seem to be using a C99 or C89/C90-compliant compiler or alternatively compile with `std=c99` or `std=c89`/`std=c90` option, because only compilers conform to standards preceding C11 warn about `gets()` being deprecated.

ISO/IEC removed the `gets()` function in C11. If you would compile with a C11 or newer standard-compliant compiler, you would get an error about the implicit declaration of `gets()` when using it in the code instead:

> "*error: implicit declaration of function `'gets'`; did you mean `'fgets'`? [`-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`]*"

---

If you want to suppress the warning at compilation, use the `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` option at compiling to disable the diagnostic for deprecated declarations.

From the GCC online docs:

> -Wno-deprecated-declarations
>
> Do not warn about uses of functions, variables, and types marked as deprecated by using the deprecated attribute. (see Function Attributes, see Variable Attributes, see Type Attributes.)
>
> Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html

If you want to embed the suppression of the warning in your code use the approach used in David´s deleted answer implementing a suppression for `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` by using `#pragma`:

```
   char str[256];

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    gets(str);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Nice answer, edited since my answer is no longer helpful